# Unexpected behaviour in aws Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have observed some unexpected behaviour in AWS Redshift. Below are the examples that illustrate it.

This query:

```
WITH var_table AS (
SELECT
    8 AS x
)
SELECT * FROM real_table
WHERE real_table_col_1 = (select x from var_table)
AND real_table_col_2 = (select x from var_table)
```

fails with:

```
ERROR: Assert
  Detail: 
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Assert
  code:      1000
  context:   query->a_last_plan()->m_locus == LocusXNode - 
  query:     48508061
  location:  xen_execute.cpp:8916
  process:   padbmaster [pid=2659]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

This query works normally:

```
create temporary table var_table AS (
SELECT
    8 AS x
);

SELECT * FROM real_table
WHERE real_table_col_1 = (select x from var_table)
AND real_table_col_2 = (select x from var_table)
```

And also this query works normally:

```
WITH var_table AS (
SELECT
    8 AS x
)
SELECT * FROM real_table
WHERE real_table_col_1 = (select x from var_table)
```

Only difference between this one and the first one is that I extract `x` only once.

Is there any explanation for this and I just don't understand some nitty-gritties of Redshift or is it a legitimate bug?

EDIT:

The query format above is a simplified version which I thought was the minimal reproducible example. I have since found out that this issue doesn't happen in some simpler queries if I use the same pattern.

I will keep trying to find the minimal reproducible example for some time, but otherwise I will just keep the `create temporary table` for now.

Comment: Does the error persist if you cast real_table_col_1 and real_table_col_2 to integers within the query? `where real_table_col_2::integer = (select x from var_table)`

Comment: Yes the error persists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assert errors are due to some part of the query plan not making sense when the query is executed.  Is it a bug? Possibly, but likely should be handled more gracefully.

I suspect that the error is arising due to the comparison of a value to a column with '=' and doing this multiple times and the table reference being a CTE (no meta data).  The query planner is setting up for the general case for this type of comparison which could be mapped to an IN clause or a JOIN.  As suspect it is trying to map to a pair of JOINs and things are going sideways.

A few things to try to see if it is such an issue:

Remove the unneeded second table scan (unnecessarily rescanning tables is not a best practice):

```
WITH var_table AS (
SELECT
    8 AS x
)
SELECT * FROM real_table
WHERE real_table_col_1 = (select x from var_table)
AND real_table_col_2 = real_table_col_1;
```

Tell the query planner that you only want 1 row from this table:

```
WITH var_table AS (
SELECT
    8 AS x
)
SELECT * FROM real_table
WHERE real_table_col_1 = (select top 1 x from var_table)
AND real_table_col_2 = (select top 1 x from var_table)
```

Move to an explicit JOIN syntax:

```
WITH var_table AS (
SELECT
    8 AS x
)
SELECT * FROM real_table rt
JOIN var_table vt
ON rt.real_table_col_1 = vt.x 
AND rt.real_table_col_2 = vt.x;
```

See if you can't recreate the issue by explicitly using redundant joins:

```
WITH var_table AS (
SELECT
    8 AS x
)
SELECT * FROM real_table rt
JOIN vart_table vt1 ON rt.real_table_col_1 = vt1.x
JOIN vart_table vt2 ON rt.real_table_col_2 = vt2.x;
```

I'm not confident that this last query will fail but I expect it is similar to what the query planner is trying to do with your original query.

Comment: The purpose of this var_table is to simulate reusable variables in Redshift. I tried doing the select top 1 but it doesn't work. The approach with join seems to be working though, so it seems that something similar to your answer must  be happening. Will accept it  tomorrow if I find nothing new. Thank you fro your input!

Comment: I wasn't confident about the "top 1" approach to provide Redshift with a hint about the data.  Looks like it is still getting itself confused even with this.  The single join approach is likely the best way to write this as it helps Redshift get the query plan to a better place.  One thing about Redshift is that it is very scan focused (metadata optimizing) and doesn't always see the optimizations users expect it to find.

Comment: Just for fun this is what ChatGPT thinks:
The error message suggests that the issue may be related to the LocusXNode in the xen_execute.cpp file. This is likely an internal implementation detail of AWS Redshift, and without more information it is difficult to say exactly what is causing the issue.

If you are experiencing unexpected behavior with AWS Redshift, it is recommended that you reach out to AWS Support for assistance. They will be able to provide more detailed information about the issue and help you resolve it. Additionally, they may be able to provide information about po...